# Spoofed MAC address with macchanger but cant connect to internet

Tags: network, ubuntu, mac-address, mac-spoofing, ipv6

So I used macchanger to spoof my mac address with these commands:

```
sudo ifconfig (interface) down
sudo macchanger -m (mac_address) (interface)
sudo ifconfig (interface) up
```

If I stop here I will not be able to connect to the internet.

So I restart network-manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

A this point after the service restart is done the mac address is set to default meaning the real mac address.

I think the issue is relevant to ipv6 because I disabled ipv6 from boot loader /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 quiet splash"
```

Following guidance below that I should use

```
sudo macchanger -r (interface) or sudo machchanger -a (interface)
```

I tried all commands from `-A random` to `-M custom mac address`, again no access to the internet if I dont restart the service network-manager.

I'm using the network adapter awus036nha

Comment: Keep in mind once you successfully connect that your connection might be very unstable if another active user is on that subnet with that mac address. If you are doing something like bypassing a public wifi subscription validator or something like that, you might need to hop around several mac addresses until you find one that is not active.

Comment: I understand and no im not trying to do that so I dont think thats the issue

Comment: You must restart the `service networking` or reload the interface with `ifdown/ifup <interface>`

Comment: @Sorcha yes, but the thing is as I said above that when I restart the network manager everything is set back to normal mac address,ipv6 configuration and such. I think the issue is that Im using a wireless adapter to connect to my access point and the communication between the ap and the adapter is lost because of changing the mac address

Comment: NetworkManager has its own built-in functionality for spoofing MAC addresses. It's not necessary to use macchanger.

Answer (score 3):

Try `sudo macchanger -r (interface)` or `sudo machchanger -a (interface)`

**While interface is down**, then bring it back up again.

Comment: @wireghoul thanks for the answer still the same issue. I tried all these commands from -A random to -M custom mac address, again no access to the internet if I dont restart the service network-manager.

Im using the network adapter awus036nha

Answer (score 0):

You've perhaps got your card stuck in rfmon mode, or something similar. Disable gnome/kde's wifi managers before using `macchanger`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you - I also had disabled ipv6 via the grub config. I undid the changes, updated the grub config, rebooted, and I am now able to change my mac addy again with macchanger.